# Check my proof: Prove that if $f$ is defined as having a positive disntinuity at $c$ and $0$ otherwise on [a,b], it is Darboux integrable

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, riemann-sum

Prove that if $f$ is defined as having a positive discontinuity at $c$ and $0$ otherwise on [a,b], it is Darboux integrable and its integral is 0.

> $\forall \epsilon>0,$ choose $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{2f(c)}$ if $\frac{\epsilon}{2f(c)}<(a-b)$ and choose $\delta=a-b$ if otherwise.
>
> For Case 1: Choose a Partition P $\{a=x_1,x_2,..., x_n=b\}$ where size of any interval is $\delta$.
>
> Then, $U(f;P)\leq\sum \sup f(x)\delta + 2f(c)\delta$ since c may lie on the boundary of an interval. Which is $=\epsilon.$
>
> For Case 2: Use the Partition with only 1 subinterval, [a,b].
>
> Then, $U(f;P)=f(c)(a-b)\leq\frac{\epsilon}{2}\leq\epsilon$ Reason:  $\frac{\epsilon}{2f(c)}\geq(a-b)$ implies $\epsilon /2 \geq f(c)(a-b)$

Q.E.D

Does the above proof works?

Comment: Could you please define what "positive discontinuity" at $c$ means? I'd think that the left and right limit of $f$ at $c$ would somehow be involved.